# Nautilus: Open with Vim

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, nautilus, terminator

I'm using arch linux with gnome and I try to open text files with vim by using nautilus. I already created a vim.desktop file in my `.local/share/applications` folder [image: vim.desktop].

If I choose Vim in Nautilus, nothing happens. My default terminal doesn't work and I already tried to change my default terminal to terminator, but it didn't work. Maybe there is an other option to change the .desktop file to forcing nautilus to open a new terminator window with vim. I guess I need to change the exec parameter.

Comment: Map it to something like: `terminator -e 'vim "$@"' "$@"` or make a wrapper script that calls that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VIM
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=vim %f
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
Keywords=Text;Editor;
```